# Smooth scroll to anchor without using hash tag?

Tags: jquery, anchor, slideshow, smooth-scrolling

I have a jQuery slideshow set up and I need to anchor link from a slide caption to a div lower on the page and use a jQuery smooth scroll.

I'd use the usual anchor code with a hashtag, but my slideshow is already using hashtags to create a permalink URL for each slide.

Example: slideshow.html#slide-1, slideshow.html#slide-2

So if I use an anchor tag to a div (a href="#lower-div") it replaces the hash tag of the permalink.

Is there a way to smooth scroll to an anchor without using a hash tag in the href?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```
$("#linkID").click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#lower-div').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
```

On click of the anchor tag with ID `linkID` smooth scroll to the `lower-div`.